# Having an issue in installing ecapture in Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, image-capture

An error shows up when I tried to install ecapture. I am unsure of what is causing it.

Input: `pip install ecapture`

Result: `note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image Failed to build scikit-image ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I tried doing `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`
but no luck

I was wondering if Python 3.10.2 supports the latest version of ecapture, right now? Or am I missing something that I should do?

Comment: Which operating system?  `scikit-image` has to compile some modules, which means you must have a compiler.

Comment: I have windows os

Comment: Here is where Anaconda as a distro shines - precompiled installs on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ecapture package requires an older version (0.14.2, released January 2019) of `scikit-image`. (The current version of `scikit-image` at time of writing is 0.19.2.)

This version of `scikit-image` *predates* Python 3.10, so there will likely be no binary packages available for it.

That means you have to build the package yourself. Since `scikit-image` is **not** a pure Python package, it means you will have to compile some C or C++ code.
For ms-windows, this requires that you have to set up a working C(++) compiler.

You can find instructions how to do that in the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers).

Answer (score -1):

Install python 3.10.2 and retry

Comment: Why do you think that will help?

Comment: Some versions of python do not support ecapture, that's why. I think that python3.9 or python 10.2 may support

Comment: The last release of `ecapture` was in May 2019, which even predates even Python 3.8 (October 2019). If anything, newer versions won't support it.